# File Browser do Sublime Text simplesmente sumiu

Tags: sublime-text-2

A lista de arquivos do Sublime Text simplesmente desapareceu. Não consigo reativar. Já baixei a versão 2, já tentei a versão 3 Beta. Não consigo fazer aparecer novamente.

O que pode ter acontecido? Alguém teve algum problema similar?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> não funciona.
**View > Show sidebar** não existe. (***View > Hide sidebar*** está desabilitado)

Comment: Qual SO esta usando?

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu 13.10).
Engraçado é que uso o Sublime há quase 1 ano e só agora o file browser deu esse probleminha.

Comment: Fazer <C+k> <C+b> em sequência não funciona?

Comment: Não, não funciona.

Comment: @xmdenis - o meu File Browser só aparece após eu abrir a pasta com o projeto, em **File > Open Folder**. Depois que eu faço isso, o side bar aparece e os atalhos funcionam normalmente.

Answer (score -1):

Vai em View,  Side Bar e Show Open File.

Comment: Acredito que uma imagem (screenshot) pode demonstrar melhor.

Answer (score -1):

Só ir em `File` e depois em `Open Folder...` E aí escolher o diretório mais alto onde deseja trabalhar.

Answer (score -2):

Vá na opção view/visualizar => side bar/barra lateral => show side bar/ mostrar barra lateral ou  pressione Ctrl + K e Ctrl + B.

Comment: Isso não funciona.